# How to compare and fetch fields from multiple log files using elasticsearch.rb filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-grok

I am parsing two differnt log files in logstash and storing it in different index.

```
<PostalSender>
        <PostalArea>
          <CreationDateTime>2015-02-26</CreationDateTime>
          <PostalID>90000</PostalID>
          </PostalArea>
</PostalSender> 


<PostalReceiver>
        <PostalArea>
          <PostalNo>90000</PostalNo>
        </PostalArea>
</PostalReceiver>
```

I want to compare the postalid and postalno, if both the fields have equal value then I have to add the field creationdatetime in reciever index and to dispaly that field in kibana.
I am using below filter

```
if[type]=="receiver"{
elasticsearch {
              hosts => ["localhost"]
              query => "type:sender %{[pp.PostalID]}"
             add_field => {"datetime"=>"pp.CreationDate"}
}
}
```

I am not getting the new field "datetime" added in my reciever index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the mix of Logstash configuration and XML in the first code block mean?

Comment: @MagnusBäck I edited the code now. The first block represents the two different xml file.

Comment: So you're trying to correlate events from two different log files? That's not possible with Logstash and its stock plugins. You'd have to write a custom plugin or it, but I'm not sure Logstash is the right tool for this task.